# SAP Customer Data Cloud (Gigya) Facebook Graphi API integration

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication, sap-commerce-cloud, gigya

As per the documentation on developers.gigya.com Gigya currently supports Facebook Graph API version 2.5. However the current version which is being used while creating facebook developer app for social login is 3.1 + .

If we use Gigya for facebook login integration will this be feasible ?

Comment: Depends mainly on whether this is trying to use any features that have been removed in the mean time …

Comment: I will be using only login which will get me the first name and last name of the user

Comment: That should work fine, there have been no relevant changes in that basic regard between those API versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.